# jQuery error in console with Lightning aura:if

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Was trying to render a basic conditional section/div using `aura:if` tag.

It throws an error when the button is included inside conditional block.

> Uncaught TypeError: a.getAttribute is not a function

**Note**:

1. **No jQuery or external libraries is included.**
2. *This error is not breaking any functionality, would like to know the cause*.

---

Here is the code:

**component**:

```
<!-- attribute -->
<aura:attribute name="page" type="String" default="1"/>

<!-- conditional view -->
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.page == '1'}">
    First page
    <button type="button" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-button--brand"
        onclick="{!c.firstStepAction}">Next</button>
    <aura:set attribute="else">
        Second page
        <button type="button" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-button--brand"
            onclick="{!c.secondStepAction}">Previous</button>
    </aura:set>
</aura:if>
```

**controller**:

```
({
    // to navigate from first to second step
    firstStepAction: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.page", '2');
    },
    // to navigate from first to second step
    secondStepAction: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.page", '1');
    }
})
```

Error in console (not breaking any functionality):

[image]

---

It works if I move the button out of `aura:if` as below:

```
<!-- attribute -->
<aura:attribute name="page" type="String" default="1"/>

<!-- buttons moved out of aura:if -->
<button type="button" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-button--brand"
    onclick="{!c.firstStepAction}">Next</button>
<button type="button" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-button--brand"
    onclick="{!c.secondStepAction}">Previous</button>

<!-- conditional view -->
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.page == '1'}">
    First page

    <aura:set attribute="else">
        Second page

    </aura:set>
</aura:if>
```

Comment: Do you get the error in a different browser that has no or different browser extensions installed?

Comment: You are right, Exception was from a chrome plugin. I had not tried this in different browser as another page with similar functionality was working fine. Thanks for your help and please post this as an answer; so that I can mark it as answered.

Comment: Added an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the comments, a Chrome extension was generating the error.

Browser extensions have very privileged access - see e.g. [Browser Extensions Are a Privacy Nightmare: Stop Using So Many of Them](https://www.howtogeek.com/188346/why-browser-extensions-can-be-dangerous-and-how-to-protect-yourself/) - and so can add to the browser window and interfere with code you are developing or using.

Comment: Earlier it used to show the exception in file name of the error in console. I guess they have removed it from name and now it shows `chrome-extension://{extensionId}` only when we hover.